# Python: setting size of a queue in a multithreading script

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, queue

I have a `client.py` script that reads URLs from txt file and send them to server. This script has multithreading for sending URLs. When URLs are read from a txt file, a queue is formed, which is then used by threads to send URLs to the server. Since the file with URLs can be very large, I need to limit the queue. When I specify `maxsize` - the script is stuck after the queue is formed. If I don't specify `maxsize`  - everything works fine.
Where is my mistake? I'm not familiar with treading and queues, maybe I need to use `queue.join()` or `queue.task_done()`? If yes, where to implement them?
**client.py:**

```
import socket
from pathlib import Path
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue


class UrlConverter:
    def load(self, filename: str):
        urls_file_path = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path(filename))
        # queue = Queue() # works fine
        queue = Queue(maxsize=10) # stuck
        with open(urls_file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
            for line in txt_file:
                line = line.strip()
                queue.put(line)
        return queue


class Client:
    def execute(self, url: str):
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.connect(('localhost', 59999))
            sock.send(url.encode())
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            sock.close()
            print(f"{url}: {data.decode('utf-8')}\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error sending request to", url, ":", str(e))


class ClientThreads:
    def __init__(self, n: int):
        self.n = n

    def execute(self, queue):
        threads = []
        while not queue.empty():
            while len(threads) < self.n:
                client = Client()
                t = Thread(target=client.execute, args=(queue.get(),))
                t.start()
                threads.append(t)
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
            threads = []


def main():
    url_converter = UrlConverter()
    clients_threads = ClientThreads(10)

    urls_queue = url_converter.load('urls.txt', 10)
    clients_threads.execute(urls_queue)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**server.py (for example):**

```
import socket
from urllib.error import URLError

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('localhost', 59999))
sock.listen()

while True:
    client, addr = sock.accept()
    result = client.recv(1024)
    try:
        client.send(b'HI from server')
        client.close()
    except (ConnectionResetError, URLError) as e:
        error = f"Error sending request to {result.decode('utf-8')} : {str(e)}"
        client.send(error.encode())
        client.close()
```

**urls.txt (for example):**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrology
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquifer
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_water
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_pollution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_treatment
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_quality
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_scarcity
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_management
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_cycle
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precipitation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runoff
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infiltration
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundwater
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_water
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_table
```

Comment: You try to completely fill the queue in `UrlConverter.load` before you start the threads which would process the queue items. Possible solution: Create an empty queue first, start the threads (which should not terminate on an empty queue), then fill the queue. If no more items are available to fill queue, put a special stop item into the queue (number of client threads times) which is recognized by the threads and terminates them.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks! Do I need to use `queue.join()` after special stop of the threads? And `queue.task_done()` after work is done on queue item by thread?

Comment: If the program should just terminate after the work is done (instead of doing anything else afterwards), `join` and `task_done` aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of work you don't need a Queue, I'd suggest you use [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) from `multiprocessing` module. You can set how many processes the thread pool has (in this case 10). Here is a short example how you can do it:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import sleep


def work(url):
    # send URL to server here, receive some response
    # ...
    sleep(1)  # simulate work
    response = f"Work processed."
    return url, response


def main():
    with ThreadPool(processes=10) as pool, open("urls.txt", "r") as f_url:
        for url, response_from_server in pool.imap_unordered(
            work, map(str.strip, f_url)
        ):
            print(url, response_from_server)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquifer Work processed.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_quality Work processed.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrology Work processed.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_pollution Work processed.

...
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need solution with queue. I don't get it - in `main` there is line by line reading from txt file? Because it's not possible to load the whole tx file at once - it can be very large.

Comment: @zaelcovsky The `open()` returns object (`f_url` in this case) that can be lazily iterated - so you don't read the whole file into a memory.  Each thread receives one line from the file at a time.